# List the classes of a .NET namespace in powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell, class

I am trying to list the classes of a .NET namespace.

Example, a namespace `[System.IO]`. I am trying to list its classes like `[System.IO.Path]`, File, Directory, StreamReader etc.

Here when I directly type `[System.IO]` on the console I get an error that the type cannot be found. `Get-Member` doesn't help because it lists methods and properties of a class.

Does any one know how to do that?

Comment: Remember that classes in different assemblies can be in the same namespace. You're going to have to iterate through a bunch of different assemblies (you're going to have to decide which), looking for types in the `System.IO` namespace

Comment: What does this have to do with `c#`?

Comment: C# is very related to .NET I will also accept C# solutions.

Comment: You might check this link: https://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2013/04/17/how-to-do-net-reflection-in-powershell/#finding-out-which-types-are-available-in-a-given-assembly

Comment: @MikeCheel excellent!

Comment: You could refer to `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system?view=net-7.0` or just search the class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in powershell:

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes()  | Where-Object {$_.NameSpace -eq 'System.IO'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Following your comment '*C# is very related to .NET I will also accept C# solutions*', I have a quick and dirty C# solution to list all the types in the `System.IO` namespace.

The below code can easily be adapted for any namespace but note that **it only works on *loaded assemblies* in the current app domain**:

```
List<Type> types;
types = new List<Type>();

foreach (var ass in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    types.AddRange(ass.GetTypes().Where(x => x.Namespace == "System.IO"));

// Do something with the list of types
```

Listing types from non-loaded assemblies is a lot trickier.  You could enumerate all assemblies in the GAC or from specified folders, but finding every single type is nigh-on impossible given that any assembly (i.e. one I can make now) can add to `System.IO`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, it filters out junk like `System.IO.File+<<WriteAllBytesAsync>g__Core|92_0>d`, just pipe in the namespaces you want at the start:

```
'System.IO' | Write-Output -pv ns | &{process{
  [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes().
  Where{ $_.Namespace -eq $ns }.FullName -notlike '*+<*'
}} | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Or turn it into a proper function:

```
function Get-NamespaceTypes {
  param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline,Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]] $Namespace
  )
  begin {
    $sortedSet = [Collections.Generic.SortedSet[string]]::new()
  }
  process {
    try {
      $sortedSet.UnionWith(
       $(foreach( $p in $PSBoundParameters['Namespace'] ){
          [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes().Where{
            $_.Namespace -eq $p
          }.FullName.Where{
            -not $_.Contains('+<')
          }
        }) -as 'string[]'
      )
    }
    catch {
      $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
  }
  end {
    return $sortedSet
  }
}
```